# Gstreamer Bus is hangup with many simultaneous pipelines running

Tags: video, gstreamer, glib

I've got program with twenty simultaneous running gstreamer pipelines (see below). But I've got a problem: in starting cycle for pipelines gstreamer bus not working until last pipeline is become PLAYING. After this gstreamer bus is showing messages from all pipelines, but this messages are already irrelevant. Pleas help me how to make changes to all bus messages should be received independently of other pipelines.

```
MainLoop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
for (int i = 0; i < Pipes.size(), i++)
 Pipes[i].Start();
g_main_loop_run(MainLoop);
```

Comment: Based on your description, Pipes[i].Start() is the problem (it's probably not returning early as it should) but you're not showing it...

Comment: I think that pipelines is starting in one same thread... The possible reason because bus messages is shown later is that my pipelines contains queue element which is running in separate own thread. May be  I need trying to starting each pipeline in separate thread with pthread_create()...

Comment: Pipes[i].Start() makes pipeline' elements, linking its and set pipeline to PLAYING state.

Comment: I'm going to be very surprised if adding threads is necessary (or useful) here. Without seeing any relevant code there's no way to give better advice either.